# SQL Merge multiple columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that is combining two tables, but I've recently been asked to add case conditions. The conditions are working but the problem I'm running into is that each condition creates a duplicate column.

```
case when s.Department = 'Aero' then '(OA)' else '' end as Blah,
case when s.Department = 'Terrent' then '(OT)' else '' end as Blah,
case when s.Department = 'Vertigo' then '(OMG)' else '' end as Blah

This causes me to end up with

a| b | c | d | Blah | Blah | Blah|
 |   |   |   | (OT) | (OA) | (OT)|
 |   |   |   | (OT) |      |     |
 |   |   |   | (OT) | (OA) |     |
 |   |   |   | (OT) | (OA) | (OT)|
 |   |   |   |      |      | (OT)|
```

How can I use the "case" cmd and have all the results if applicable show up under 1 column?

```
a| b | c | d | Blah |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OA) |
 |   |   |   | (OA) |
 |   |   |   | (OA) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
 |   |   |   | (OT) |
```

Comment: I'm confused.  How can department take on the values `'Aero'`, `'Terrent'`, and `'Vertigo'` -- as implied by the first row of your desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use one case statement instead of three:

```
 (case when s.Department = 'Aero' then '(OA)' 
      when s.Department = 'Terrent' then '(OT)' 
      when s.Department = 'Vertigo' then '(OMG)'
      else ''
  end) as Blah
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, Thanks.

Comment: Last question. Now how can I take the finished product (there are multiple joins in my statement) and insert it into a permanent table?

Comment: @stackrack . . . You could use the the `select . . . into . . .` statement (put the `into` before the `from`).  Alternatively, you could set up a view that returns the results, but does not actually materialize a table.

Comment: Dude, you just saved me like three hours with that view suggestion. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!